# Save intermediate list output in dplyr pipeline and map it back to another list further down the pipeline - R

Tags: r, dplyr, pca, ggbiplot

I am running pcas on groups in a data set using `dplyr` pipelines. I am starting with `group_split`, so am working with a list. In order to run the `prcomp()` function, only the `numeric` columns of each list can be included, but I would like the `factor` column brought back in for plotting at the end. I have tried saving an intermediate output using `{. ->> temp}` partway through the pipeline, but since it is a list, I don't know how to index the grouping column when plotting.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggbiplot)

iris %>%
  group_split(Species, keep = T) %>% #group by species, one pca per species
  {. ->> temp} %>%  # save intermediate output to preserve species column for use in plotting later
  map(~.x %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% select_if(~var(.) != 0) %>% 
        prcomp(scale. = TRUE))%>% #run pca on numeric columns only
  map(~ggbiplot(.x), label=temp$Species)#plot each pca, labeling points as species names form the temporary object
```

This works to produce one pca plot for each species in the `iris`data set, but since `temp$species = NULL`, the points are not labelled.

Comment: can you save `temp <- unique(iris$Species)` first without saving it as intermediate output and then use it in `map(~ggbiplot(.x), label=temp)` ? Also is `ggbiplot` not available for R 3.6.1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `map2()` and pass the `.y` argument as the species list you can get the result I think you want.  Note that in your original code the `labels` argument was outside the `ggbiplot()` function and was ignored.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggbiplot)

iris %>%
  group_split(Species, keep = T) %>% 
  {. ->> temp} %>%  
  map(~.x %>% 
        select_if(is.numeric) %>%
        select_if(~var(.) != 0) %>% 
        prcomp(scale. = TRUE)) %>% 
  map2(map(temp, "Species"), ~ggbiplot(.x, labels = .y))
```

[image]

In response to your comment, if you wanted to add a third argument you could use `pmap()` instead of `map2()`. In the example below, `pmap()` is being passed a (nested) list of the data for the `ggbiplot()` arguments. Note I've changed the `new` variable so that it's a factor and not constant across groups.

```
iris %>%
  mutate(new = factor(sample(1:3, 150, replace = TRUE))) %>%
  group_split(Species, keep = T) %>% 
  {. ->> temp} %>%  
  map(~.x %>% 
        select_if(is.numeric) %>%
        select_if(~var(.) != 0) %>% 
        prcomp(scale. = TRUE)) %>% 
  list(map(temp, "Species"), map(temp, "new")) %>%
  pmap(~ ggbiplot(pcobj = ..1, labels = ..2, groups = ..3))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Do I know how I might introduce a `.z` element in the `ggbiplot` call? Something like `~ggbiplot(.x, labels = .y, groups=.z)`, if the data had another grouping column? Eg. `iris$new<-c(rep('a',50),rep('b',50),rep('c',50))`

Comment: @J.Con - For the `map()` family, to use functions with more than 2 arguments you can change the notation to `..1`, `..2`, `..3` etc.

Comment: Thank you. I’m sorry but I just can’t figure it out?

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `split` and `imap`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggbiplot)
iris %>%
split(.$Species) %>%  # save intermediate output to preserve species column for use in plotting later
map(~.x %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% select_if(~var(.) != 0) %>% 
        prcomp(scale. = TRUE)) %>% 
imap(~ggbiplot(.x, labels = .y))
```